# Calcular média de distância percorrida com único tapply

Tags: r

Tenho meu banco de dados proveniente do pacote `hflights` do R, que mostra uma quantidade de voos nos EUA. Preciso calcular a média da distância percorrida (`Distance`) para cada dia da semana (variável `DayofWeek`) entre os voos com atraso maior que 60 e entre os com atraso menor que 60 (variavel `DepDelay`). É necessário usar um único `tapply`.

Tentei algo parecido com isso, mas está errado:

```
y=(c(which(sapply(dados,is.numeric))))y 
apply(as.matrix(y),1,function(x){tapply(dados[,x],list(dados$DayofWeek,dados$DepDelay>60),mean)})
```

Comment: Felipe se alguma resposta atendeu a sua pergunta, você pode aceitá-la clicando no botão verde de ok do lado esquerdo da resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Ao meu ver a forma mais elegante de fazer isso é usando os pacotes `dplyr`e `tidyr`. O código usando essas funções fica muito mais simples de ler. Vale a pena aprender!

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

hflights %>% 
  filter(!is.na(DepDelay)) %>% # filtra os voos sem atraso
  mutate(DepDelay2 = ifelse(DepDelay>60, ">60", "<=60")) %>% # atraso maior que 60
  group_by(DayOfWeek, DepDelay2) %>% # indica o calculo em grupo
  summarise(media = mean(Distance)) %>% # usa a media para agregar
  spread(DepDelay2, media) # coloca em colunas separadas

# Source: local data frame [7 x 3]
# 
#   DayOfWeek      <60      >60
# 1         1 783.1453 796.0078
# 2         2 778.1595 796.8847
# 3         3 779.2828 816.0626
# 4         4 782.5144 816.7166
# 5         5 785.8960 790.0505
# 6         6 823.0040 821.7922
# 7         7 797.2524 803.0468
```

Answer (score 1):

Não sei como fazer isso para os dois grupos (`DepDelay > 60` e `DepDelay < 60`) utilizando **um único** `tapply`, mas eu faria assim para cada um dos grupos:

```
tapply(X = hflights[which(hflights$DepDelay > 60),"Distance"], INDEX = hflights[which(hflights$DepDelay > 60),"DayOfWeek"], FUN = mean)
tapply(X = hflights[which(hflights$DepDelay < 60),"Distance"], INDEX = hflights[which(hflights$DepDelay < 60),"DayOfWeek"], FUN = mean)
```

Só note que há também 232 casos com `DepDelay == 60`, caso você queira considerar todos os vôos (não-cancelados) da base de dados.

**EDITADO**
 
 Aqui está uma forma (não muito elegante) de se fazer isso com **um único** `tapply`:

```
tapply(X = hflights$Distance, INDEX = list(hflights$DayOfWeek, ifelse(test = hflights$DepDelay > 60, yes = "> 60", no = "<= 60")), FUN = mean)
```

O único problema é que dessa forma você precisa incluir os 232 casos com `DepDelay == 60` em algum dos dois grupos (no meu código eu coloquei no segundo grupo, `DepDelay < 60`)

Answer (score 1):

Outras duas formas de fazer:

Usando `tapply`, como o Nishimura, mas com o `cut`. O legal do cut é que ele estende facilmente para mais do que duas condições, basta aumentar os breaks e os labels:

```
tapply(X = dados$Distance, 
       INDEX = list(dados$DayOfWeek,
                    cut(dados$DepDelay, 
                        breaks =c(-Inf, 60, Inf), 
                        labels = c("menor60", "maior60"))),
       FUN = mean)
```

Usando o `dplyr` sem `cut`:

```
dados %>% 
  group_by(DayOfWeek) %>% 
  summarise(menor60 = mean(Distance[DepDelay <= 60], na.rm = TRUE),
            maior60 = mean(Distance[DepDelay > 60], na.rm = TRUE))
```

A solução do dplyr com `cut` seria equivalente à resposta do Daniel trocando o `ifelse`.